# Importing time series with json_normalize from opentsdb

Tags: json, pandas, time-series, normalize

Trying to import data from OpenTSDB using json_normalize. Somehow it worked for most field except the values of each timestamp.

I've tried to change different settings and even the `.T` at the end for time series which I got somewhere around here. Although, that did not help.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {
    "metric": "peer.traffic.in",
    "tags": {"site": "site1", "peer": "peer1"},
    "aggregateTags": [],
    "dps": {"1561953835": 19565.66015625, "1561954125": 19012.55078125, "1561954439": 17274.669921875, "1561954728": 19151.75, "1561955039": 17603.23046875, "1561955329": 17056.1796875, "1561955641": 16232.349609375, "1561955928": 17016.48046875, "1561956241": 16023.0498046875, "1561956533": 15529.1298828125, "1561956847": 14976.080078125, "1561957126": 14557.6796875}
}

df = json_normalize(data, record_path=['dps'], meta=['metric',['tags','site'],['tags','peer']])
print (df)
```

Output :

```
             0           metric tags:site tags:peer
0   1561953835  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
1   1561954125  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
2   1561954439  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
3   1561954728  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
4   1561955039  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
5   1561955329  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
6   1561955641  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
7   1561955928  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
8   1561956241  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
9   1561956533  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
10  1561956847  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
11  1561957126  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
```

I would expect to see the values to show up in the table from the `dps` table.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Both timestamp and it's associated value.

Answer (score 0):

According to [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) record_path can't handle dictionary as input. You need to deliver proper data format:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {
    "metric": "peer.traffic.in",
    "tags": {"site": "site1", "peer": "peer1"},
    "aggregateTags": [],
    "dps": {"1561953835": 19565.66015625, "1561954125": 19012.55078125, "1561954439": 17274.669921875, "1561954728": 19151.75, "1561955039": 17603.23046875, "1561955329": 17056.1796875, "1561955641": 16232.349609375, "1561955928": 17016.48046875, "1561956241": 16023.0498046875, "1561956533": 15529.1298828125, "1561956847": 14976.080078125, "1561957126": 14557.6796875}
}

# convert dict values into list
data['dps'] = [str(i) for i in list(data.get('dps').values())]


df = json_normalize(data=data, record_path='dps', meta=['metric',['tags','site'],['tags','peer']])
```

Output:

```
                   0           metric tags.site tags.peer
0     19565.66015625  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
1     19012.55078125  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
2    17274.669921875  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
3           19151.75  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
4     17603.23046875  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
5      17056.1796875  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
6    16232.349609375  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
7     17016.48046875  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
8   16023.0498046875  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
9   15529.1298828125  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
10   14976.080078125  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
11     14557.6796875  peer.traffic.in     site1     peer1
```

Comment: I needed both the timestamp and value. Is that possible?